# Can Maven package a WAR as .tar.gz?

Tags: maven, docker, packaging

I'm building a WAR application in Maven and I need to deploy it to Docker. The issue is that docker doesn't support the zip format (but can use a .tar.gz or .tar.xz).

So, how can I package my `mywebapp-1.0.0.war` as `mywebapp-1.0.0.tar.gz`?

We have this requirement so it would become easier to perform the hardening steps for the docker image.

I tried using the Assembly plugin and it produces a `target/mywebapp-1.0.0.tar.gz`. However, it ends up placing the whole WAR file inside a .tar.gz file, and NOT its contents. Here's my `assembly.xml` file:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
  <id>distribution</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>target/mywebapp-1.0.0.war</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Docker needs full machine deployments, not just the war file.  You need to create the full docker image - jib can do that.  https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I find the requirement strange (the application server should unpack your war, not you), I guess it is possible by tarring the directory in `target` that is used to build the war.

Before the package step, all the files for the war are gathered in a directory just below target (I forgot the name, but it should be easy to reverse engineer) - just pack that directory by using the assembly plugin.

**Edit by the OP:**

I wanted to accept this answer but I also wanted it to be useful to someone else so I added the working solution (`assembly.xml` file). Here it is:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
  <id>docker</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>target/${project.build.finalName}</directory>
      <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

This solution generates the file `target/mywebapp-1.0.0-docker.tar.gz` in addition to the typical war file.

Notice it added the `docker` classifier.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that directory but wasn't sure if I could use it. Thanks. On a side note, for security purposes it's not recommended the app server unpacks the war. We are required (from Tomcat docs) to unpack with ownership of a different user. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but AFAIK "everybody" uploads the packed war to the server, and I never saw somebody using your procedure.

Comment: OP tries to deploy the WAR file directly to Docker itself, not a docker instance.

Comment: Ok, I start to understand.

Comment: Yes, the whole docker assembled image is published to an Artifactory server for deployment later.